# Dictionary values getting updated with last entered value pair with keys being unique

Tags: python, dictionary

```
Expected output with print(self.all_enteries)

{
  1: {
    'cach': 97,
    'pyr': 34,
    'io_mac': 78,
    'dedd': 3
  },
  2: {
    'cach': 98,
    'pyr': 54,
    'io_mac': 34,
    'dedd': 2
  },
  3: {
    'cach': 91
    'pyr': 28
    'io_mac: 19
    'dedd': 7
  },
  4: {
    'cach': 99,
    'pyr': 78,
    'io_mac 36,
    'dedd': 0
  }
}

Returned output 
All the values getting updated with last entry even when the keys are different

{
  1: {
    'cach': 99,
    'pyr': 78,
    'io_mac': 36,
    'dedd': 0
  },
  2: {
    'cach': 99,
    'pyr': 78,
    'io_mac': 36,
    'dedd': 0
  },
  3: {
    'cach': 99,
    'pyr': 78,
    'io_mac': 36,
    'dedd': 0
  },
  4: {
    'cach': 99,
    'pyr': 78,
    'io_mac': 36,
    'dedd': 0
  }
}
```

Belwo if the snippet of the code i am using where with a for loop ii am first populating single*entry and than I put single* entry in to all_enteries dict

class CPUcheck():

```
def __init__(self, emul):
    self.single_entry = {}
        self.all_entries = {}
    self.emul = emul

def populate_threads(self, iter):
    if self.emul == "ABC"
        for i in range(1, iter+1):
            # issue command on linux server and stores in a file
            cmd = "command > output.txt"
            os.system(cmd)
            # parses each line in output.txt and populates self.single_entry 
            with open("output.txt", mode="r") as file:
                for line in file.readlines():
                    # Parsing done
                    # If matchOBj found
                        self.single_entry[matchObj.group(1).strip()] = int(matchObj.group(2))
            self.all_entries[i] = self.single_entry
```

I am seeing that with last entry the previous values are getting overwritten although having unique keys

Can you please advise if i am missing something here?
Thanking everyone in advance

Answer (score 0):

You are updating the same `single_entry` instance each time. You need a new one on every iteration. Remove `single_entry` from the `__init__` and create a new dict everytime above the `with` statement:

```
def __init__(self, emul):
    self.all_entries = {}
    self.emul = emul

def populate_threads(self, iter):
    if self.emul == "ABC"
        for i in range(1, iter+1):
            # issue command on linux server and stores in a file
            cmd = "command > output.txt"
            os.system(cmd)
            # parses each line in output.txt and populates self.single_entry 
            single_entry = {}
            with open("output.txt", mode="r") as file:
                for line in file.readlines():
                    # Parsing done
                    # If matchOBj found
                        single_entry[matchObj.group(1).strip()] = int(matchObj.group(2))
            self.all_entries[i] = single_entry
```